# Using Aggregation and Summarization in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, aggregation, summary

I have a simple query that is designed to summarize `total_miles` based on a `GROUP BY` aggregation of other columns:

```
SELECT 
    tiermetric AS tier,
    st AS state, 
    validation,
    'All' AS study_type,
    SUM(total_miles) as total_miles
FROM mu_schema.my_table
WHERE validation = 'VALID'
AND st = 'VA'
GROUP BY
    tiermetric,
    state,
    validation,
    study_type 
ORDER BY tiermetric
```

Currently, it outputs:

```
tier    state   validation  study_type  total_miles
TIER 2  VA      VALID       All         335.005721465211
TIER 2  VA      VALID       All         0.337142821958635
TIER 3  VA      VALID       All         13.3444415576409
TIER 3  VA      VALID       All         1651.56942736755
TIER 4  VA      VALID       All         6606.44868771768
TIER 4  VA      VALID       All         1399.72188798074
```

I want it to output:

```
tier    state   validation  study_type  total_miles
TIER 2  VA      VALID       All         335.3421
TIER 3  VA      VALID       All         1664.9138
TIER 4  VA      VALID       All         8006.1704
```

What am I doing wrong here? I basically want the miles summarized on tier only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're grouping by `study_type`, which is a column that has two distinct values per each tier in your underlying table. You're not selecting that column though, you use a constant 'All' as that. So you simply have to remove the `study_type` column from your `GROUP BY` clause and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Yes; that was the case! It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    tiermetric AS tier,
    st AS state, 
    validation,
    'All' AS study_type,
    SUM(total_miles) as total_miles
FROM mu_schema.my_table
WHERE validation = 'VALID'
AND st = 'VA'
GROUP BY
    tiermetric,
    state,
    validation
ORDER BY tiermetric
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.